# Symfony2: Could I use 2 mechanism authentication for one firewall?

Tags: ajax, security, api, symfony

I explain. I have 2 kernel: `AdminKernel` and `ApiKernel`.

The session for api use the session of admin (in `api/config/config.yml`):

```
framework:
    session:
        save_path: %kernel.root_dir%/../admin/cache/%kernel.environment%/sessions
```

The `security.yml` is common:

```
security:

    ...    
    firewalls:
        ...
        admin_login:
            pattern:  ^/admin/user/login$
            security: false

        api:
            pattern: ^/api
            http_basic: ~

        admin:
            pattern:    ^/admin
            form_login:
                check_path: /admin/user/login_check
                login_path: /admin/user/login
                default_target_path: /admin
            logout:
                path:   /admin/user/logout
                target: /admin
            remember_me:
                key:      G>n[,O+^@F)j2_0^yFR_(|q<X~YtGD2:PV3zuktP0+/u*We]Ix$An X:m!#eeYEx
                lifetime: 3600
                path:     /
                domain:   ~ # Defaults to the current domain from $_SERVER
        ...
```

When I am on `http://localhost/admin/list`, a session is created.
And I want to use an ajax call to do some action with the URL `https://localhost/api/update/page`. The browser display the authentication box (http_basic) and it does not use the admin session.

My question is : How tell to API if the admin session exists, use it otherwise display the authentication box ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Symfony2 Docs:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html

> 1. Multiple firewalls don't share security context If you're using multiple firewalls and you authenticate against one firewall, you will
>      not be authenticated against any other firewalls automatically.
>      Different firewalls are like different security systems. To do this
>      you have to explicitly specify the same Firewall Context for different
>      firewalls. But usually for most applications, having one main firewall
>      is enough.